# Extension of an algebra over the residue field of a local ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with residue field $\kappa$ at the prime $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $A$ be a finitely generated (associative but not necessarily commutative) algebra over $\kappa$. Is it possible to "extend" the algebra $A$ to some free algebra $B$ over $R$ such that $B$ is isomorphic to $A$ when reduced mod $\mathfrak{p}$?

My naïve idea is to define over the a free algebra with generator $x_1,...,x_n$ over $R$ such that their product rules satisfy the structure constants when reduced mod $\mathfrak{p}$. However, the problem is to show that the rules satisfy the axiom of an algebra, e.g., identity, associativity and so on.

In fact, what I had in mind is: Given a local ring $R$ and a central simple algebra $A$ over the residue field, I want to define an Azumaya algebra $B$ over $R$ such that it is reduced to $A$. In fact, it is enough to define an free algebra (equivalently finite projective) algebra $B$ over $R$ which is reduced to $A$. Then it is automatically an Azumaya algebra.

Comment: You meant $B$ contains $R$, or $R\to Rb$ is injective for all $b\in B$, or something else? Because to me $A$ is already a $R$-algebra.

Comment: @reuns Right. I edited. I want to extend a central simple algebra to an Azumaya algebra.